# Should I speak out in a review with my boss?

Tags: professionalism, management, work-environment, performance-reviews

I have a review with my supervisor tomorrow. The last time I had one was a few months ago. Since then, she has accused me of lying, accused me of doing something I did not do, implied that I am unintelligent, and she ignores me when I ask her if she is happy with my progress/work on a project. Should I bring up these points during the review?

Comment: Why did you wait for the review?

Comment: Minor question, is this a review by the boss of you, or is it a for you to review your boss? Normally it's the first, so I'd assume that, however I've seen some companies allowing employees to do their own feedback with their superiors.

Comment: How certain are you that your manager is not trying to make you quit?

Answer (score 9):

You don't know ahead of time what your supervisor is going to say or do at the review.

If you unilaterally bring up your grievances, your review is most likely going to turn nasty - that would be a pity for you if she had decided to turn the page on what had happened.

Since she is your supervisor and it's her review of your performance, you'd best listen to what she has to say before you even think of speaking up - it's her review and it would behoove you to let her drive it. You are not going to counter any of her arguments unless you know what they are, and you won't know what they are unless she states them without you interrupting and disrupting her monologue. You know that any serious disagreement you have with her evaluation won't be resolved at the review, right?

If you have any serious disagreement with her review, make sure that you get that disagreement straight before you file any objection in writing with HR. Make sure that you verbally express your disagreement to her in a non-adversarial way e.g. "This is how I see it". Because you are not expressing your disagreement as part of a shouting contest or a screaming match, you are expressing your disagreement as part of the review's official record. And count on it that HR is going to read that record line by line if you have them review it.

Comment: Great answer.  Using the review to air one's own grievances would be effectively hijacking the meeting for your own purpose.  Not a great thing to do in a meeting that is about evaluating you as an employee.

Answer (score 6):

Not a great idea to go on the attack in a review although at some point you may need to. Best to prepare yourself and make sure you have all the answers sorted for anything that might come up, then play it by ear. So long as you have prepared you can't do much else.

Going on the attack will immediately make you look disgruntled and troublesome. Defending yourself calmly and professionally makes your opponent look like the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your performance review in a positive light.
Take everything she told you and even if you would disagree with her, try to bring back a positive experience **since then**.

- She said you lied: **highlight how good the communication had been on [insert here project with a happy customer]**.
- She said you did something you didn't do (that was bad I supposed): 
  **remember her how well you did this same task on another project.**
- She implied you are unintelligent: **higlight a problem you solved.**
- She ignores when you ask for feedback: **ask her what KPI she would think would be best to monitor your performance so you can improve**

Obviously, don't mention what she said and that you disagree with her.
Don't try to prove her wrong, show her the positives and the will to progress.

It's sometimes too easy to see the problems and not the good things.

Good luck!